# add second id in mysql colum alphabetically where 1st column is the id for hotel and second column is the id of the packages added

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a mysql table for hotel details where the hotel id is generated automatically and is auto incremental and another table package details where the packages for each hotel are add.

currently the package id is incremented automatically.

so 1st hotel with 5 packages have hotel id 1 & package id as 1,2,3,4,5 & 2nd hotel has hotel id 2  & package id as 6,7,8,9

but i want to make it as hotel id 1 package id 1a,1b,1c,1d,1e & 2nd hotel with hotel id 2 package id as 2a,2b, 2c, & so on

we are using php & mysql

Comment: Let mysql handle auto ids and on display, print package id as `$hotel_id . chr($package_id - 1  + ord('a'))`, something like that

Comment: this is definately showing package id as 1a, 1b, 1c, 2d & so on.   but what i want to do is 1a, 1b, 1c, 1d, 2a, 2b,2c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any **created_on** field in package table?

If yes then fetch a details of latest package using created_on field and get package id from it and do increment in format in want by php code then insert the package.

Comment: no. i just want the package id to again start from 'a' for each new hotel id

Comment: Exactly,See If any package is not present for that hotel then make id '1a' and If any package is present then you can get latest package id by created_on field and generate new package id for inserting. You have to fire select query before inserting any package.